# Group Tabs On Chrome With Keyboard Shortcuts

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

Does any one know how to make a tab into a group using only the keyboard?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One option is by installing the following Chrome Extension:

**[New Tab in Group Keyboard Shortcut](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/new-tab-in-group-keyboard/hodhmojdnjljopdihkoniodkacnpimjf)**

By default it comes set up as: **Ctrl+Shift+Y**

If you wish to change the shortcut:

- Go to [chrome://extensions/shortcuts](https://chrome://extensions/shortcuts)
- In that page search "New Tab in Group Keyboard Shortcut"
- Set up the key you want.

Comment: This doesn't fix my problem completely, I want to make a specific tab a into a NEW TAB GROUP